# unique rand number in a ruby loop

Tags: ruby

I am reading the book "Learn to program", and I have come across an exercise that I am having trouble with.

```
year = (rand(1900...1990))
while true do
puts "What would you like to say to grandma?"
  ask = gets.chomp
  if 
    ask == ask.downcase
    puts "SPEAK UP SONNY"
  elsif  
    ask == ask.upcase
    puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{year}!"

  end

  break if ask == "BYE"
end
```

everything is functioning properly, but if the rand number "year" comes up more than once, it repeats the same number.  Is there a way to have it become a unique random number each time it comes up during the same loop?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move year assignment into the loop to have it assigned before each chomp.

Comment: How does this avoid 1943 from coming up more than once?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `year` does not change within the loop because it is defined outside the loop. It would change if the definition were moved inside the loop, but you still may have years repeated. To fix both of these problems, change

```
year = rand(1900...1990)
```

to

```
years = (1900...1990).to_a.shuffle
```

(outside the loop) and change

```
puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{year}!"
```

to

```
puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{years.shift}!"
```

(or `years.pop`). If this is repeated more than 91 times an exception will be raised.